# Fetch data from server to register an account in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a project in React Native. I try fetch data from server to register account. I registered sucessfully and it shows in my database but it shows "undefined". What happened with this? Any solutions?

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Comment: You might get success but there must be an issue may be data not posting correctly or may be server not receiving params

Comment: Please provide the code that shows the registration. Does this only happens once? or all the time? I guess your handling is wrong somehow so that you pass on undefined instead of the username for example

Comment: I have post more about the code. Can you check it for me?

Comment: You should just copy the code into the Question instead of giving us pictures of it...

Comment: I've changed the image links to actual images, but please further replace these with the code itself, as text. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

Try sending this way

```
fetch("http://example.com", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({
      Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }),
  body: "param1=value1&param2=value2"
})
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseText) => {
  // alert(responseText);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```